# Can PyCharm's optimize imports also alphabetize them?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am enjoying PyCharm's optimizing of Python imports - as well as removing unused imports, following PEP8 gives them a sensible layout and makes them easier to read. Is there any way to get PyCharm to additionally alphabetize them (which would make scanning them faster, for me at least)?

Comment: alphabetical sorting only via plugin -> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5919-lines-sorter

Answer (score 36, accepted):

PyCharm does this automatically now by use of `Code -> Optimize Imports`. It also [sorts them into groups per PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/optimizing-imports.html for details.

Comment: Probably this wasn't true at some time, but now PyC really sorts the imports WITHIN a group (standard imports, libraries, own code? - or just standard vs non-standard - I have 3 groups). So far so good, but Line Sorter can have many more usages than just sorting imports.

Comment: Hmm, when I have 3rd party & built-in imports (ex: "import pytest" followed by "from datetime import datetime, time, date" followed by "import unittest") PEP8 would say the built-ins should come first (pytest would be the last import), but Pycharm puts them with pytest first, unittest 2nd, and datetime 3rd.

Comment: I had to enable the option `Sort imported names in "from" imports` in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python > Imports` for it to work with black. Unfortunately this setting is off per default. PyCharm 2023.1

Answer (score 15):

PyCharm sorts imports only according to groups specified in PEP-8, not alphabetically.

Comment: As of 2023.1, you can sort alphabetically. Set `Sort imported names in "from" imports` in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python > Imports`

Answer (score 9):

As already mentioned it seems that `Code -> Optimize imports` cannot do that.

There is however a plugin named [Lines sorter](https://github.com/syllant/idea-plugin-linessorter) (exists in the PyCharm repositories) with which one can mark all import lines and chose `Edit -> Sort lines`. Not perfect but easier than doing it all by hand.

Comment: This really helps. Search "Sort line" in settings and assign a shortcut (say F5) for it makes sorting import easier.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a nice addition to PyCharm indeed.

Until that time there's a command line tool that does what you want called [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort). It doesn't come with a plug-in for PyCharm, but can be integrated via an *External command* and the *Synchronize files after execution* option, as described [in their docs](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/wiki/isort-Plugins). You could even hook it to the original key binding.

Comment: `isort` can also be configured in pyproject.toml and pre-commit so it works for everyone on the team. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/use-isort-to-sort-your-python-module-imports-automatically-40918f3e2a8b

Answer (score 1):

Additional answer for the more vim-minded. You can install [`IdeaVim`](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, select lines to be sorted, and a call to `:sort` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As of PyCharm 2023.1, there is an option to sort imports alphabetically. This will also work with new imports added through PyCharm hints. Unfortunately this setting is off per default and not stated that it is available in the documentation.

The option is in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python > Imports`:

```
✅ Sort import statements

    ✅ Sort imported names in "from" imports
```

Despite this option, it is still not 100% compatible with code formatters like `black`. Here is an open issue on youtrack to track them: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49349