# Auto-formatting imports in PyCharm Professional Edition

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I've recently stumbled upon an issue where **IntelliJ PyCharm PE** started *auto-optimizing* my imports, but I never enabled/installed such feature, however I do have **isort** installed, I don't remember it having an option for auto-optimization though. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**Example**:
I am looking at the code:

```py
from here import this
from here2 import this2
from here1 import this1
```

And when I'm doing a commit stage via (**Alt+0**) PyCharm's commit interface it autoformats these imports to this:

```py
from here import this
from here1 import this1
from here2 import this2
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for a style guide but rather for a reason isort auto-formats my imports, sometimes it will even format files I didn't touch or opened.

Comment: I think it's the first option ["Sort imported names in "from" imports"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-style-python.html#imports_table) Do you have [optimize imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20468670) enabled in the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out Pycharm was auto formatting my imports when saving/commiting changes via a **File Watchers** feature located under *settings/Tools* section, disabling it helped with autoformatting.